# Table VS counter?

Tags: word-choice, comparisons

What is the difference between *counter* and *table*, in the context of a surface that one might eat at (as in *the kitchen counter* or *the kitchen table*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Counter* can be used as short for *countertop*, which is (NOAD) *a flat surface for working on, especially in a kitchen*.
The first definition given from the NOAD for *counter* is

> a long flat-topped fixture in a store or bank across which business is conducted with customers.
>     • a similar structure used for serving food and drinks in a cafeteria or bar.

I would interpret *counter* as to mean, for example, the fixture you can usually see in an American kitchen and that is used for breakfast; its structure reminds me of the counter you find in a bar.
The difference with the table is that the table is less height.

When I visit USA in my frequent trips, I hear the word *counter* being used as synonym of *countertop*, which is *a flat surface for working on, especially in a kitchen*. This is could be valid in the specific place I go (Long Island, Suffolk County), though.

Comment: I think using *counter* for *countertop* is used throughout the US.  It is also referred to as *kitchen counter*.  Many in the US use the term *countertop* to refer exclusively to the slab that sits upon the lower cupboards that make up the '*counter*'.

Comment: In my case, the word is used to mean the fixture to the sides of the kitchen sink, or the stove. When I ask where the keys are, I am replied they are on the counter, and I discover they are on a fixture to the right of the sink and where the microwave is.

Answer (score 3):

The counter is a built-in fixture, typically consisting of the countertop (made of stone, sturdy plastic, Formica, or concrete) and the cabinet (made of sheet-metal or wood).  In the US, the surface of the counter is almost universally 36" off the floor.  It's usually made to measure.

A table is a piece of furniture, generally made entirely of wood (although metal-and-Formica creations are not unknown) and consisting of the tabletop and either legs or a central pedestal.  The top surface is about 30" from the floor (comfortable for eating but too low for working from a standing position).  A table is generally purchased ready-made from a store that also sells chairs, couches, and other furniture.